# apt upgradeしてもAnacondaのSpyderがアップデートされない

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

色々勉強しようとメイン機で使用するOSをUbuntuLTSに切り替えて、パッケージ管理Aptが便利だったのでCLIから色々ソフトなどをインストールしたのですが、それらのアップデートがあればまとめてインストールするようなコマンドはございますか？
ちなみにPythonのAnacondaディストリビューション内のSpyderの新規Verは

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

を走らせてもアップデートされていませんでした。

加えて、ソフトウェア以外でGPUなどのドライバーもアップデート出来るコマンドもあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APT はあくまでパッケージアーカイブで管理されている各種パッケージのバージョンを管理するものです。

Anaconda が推奨している方法を使った場合、Anaconda は APT とは関係なく独立にインストールされるよう操作したはずです。したがって `apt upgrade` を使っても Anaconda 自身や Anaconda が管理しているパッケージには影響がありません。むしろ影響があると困ります。Anaconda が管理しているパッケージの更新は Anaconda で行ってください。

GPU ドライバーに関しても、どのようにインストールされたかによります。APT でインストールされたなら APT で管理されますし、そうでないならそうでないです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうだったんですね。
Ubuntuならdpkg -lコマンドで出てくるパッケージ群のみがアップデート可能、という認識であっていますでしょうか？

Comment: インストール可能か更新可能かで話が変わってきます。APTにはリポジトリの概念があり、最初から有効になっている公式リポジトリ以外にも第三者のリポジトリを追加することができます。`dpkg -l` で一覧できるのは現在既に追加されているリポジトリで配布されているパッケージのみですので、リポジトリを追加することによって管理できるようになるパッケージは表示されていません。このため現在の設定でインストール可能なパッケージ一覧が `dpkg -l`、既にインストールされていて更新があれば利用できるパッケージ一覧が `apt list --installed` です。